# How to add the ability to search for a set of words in the application?

Tags: python, string, list

*Condition:*

1. The search words need to be stored in the list;
2. Search regardless of the case of the letters of the word;
3. A word can be separated from other words by a space, punctuation marks;
4. If the word is in the text, but in an inverted form, it should be taken into account in the search statistics.
5. You cannot use split.

My current code:

The problem is that it only accepts one word, not a sentence. I tried to translate searchW into a list, but this leads to errors (TypeError: list indexes must be integers or slices, not str).

```
def task1(text,searchW):
for i in text:
if i.isalpha():
letters.append(i)
res = "".join(letters).lower() #combine characters
count = res.count(searchW.lower()) +res.count(searchW[::-1].lower()) # finding words and
inverted versions and counting their number
if len(res) != len(searchW):
count+=0
print(f"words found in normal and inverted form - {count} times(a).")
text = input("enter text:")
searchW = input("enter search words:")
letters = [ ] #a list that consists of letters contained in the text
task1(text=text,searchW= searchW)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the correct code indentation

Comment: `searchW = input()` will always be a single string. So, if you cannot split it, what else have you tried to make it a list?

Comment: I tried to convert it into a list.`SearchWList = list(searchW)`. But it did not work.

Comment: That will create a list of characters from a single string, not split on spaces or punctuation for multiple words

Comment: I understand. However, what can I do to create a list that will accept words?

Comment: if you can't use `split()` then you can find space position `pos = searchW.find(" ")` and slice it `word = searchW[:pos]` and repeat it for rest of string `searchW = searchW[pos+1:]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to get a list of words

```
text = input("enter text:")
searchW = [] 
print("enter search words:")
while True:
    s = input("> ").strip()
    if not s:
        break
    searchW.append(s)

task1(text, searchW)
```

Then sum the counts over each word

```
count = 0
for w in searchW:
    w = w.lower()
    count += res.count(w) 
    count += res.count(w[::-1])
```

You shouldn't compare the length of res string to the length of the search list

> A word can be separated from other words by a space, punctuation marks

If your have text `car.at`, then `rat` search word will be counted by your code... Unclear if that's expected. If not, you need to rethink your `res` variable